# Is it possible to return a double with scientific notation in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm currently doing a code kata (this one: https://www.codewars.com/kata/evaluate-mathematical-expression/train/cpp) and in one of the random tests, it states:

```
Expected: equal to -1286.49 (+/- 1e-06)

Actual: -1286.49
```

It seems like the kata wants me to include scientific notation. However, the return type can only be a double, not a string.

Is there any way to do so with a double return type in C++? Thanks.

Comment: "Scientific notation" is only a presentational thing, when you read or print the floating point value as text.

Comment: And the expected output seems to be with some error limits, it's not pure scientific notation presentation.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted the error message. I assume the error message means, that `|expected - actual| > 1e-06`.

Comment: What code with what data produces that output?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use scientific notation when converting a floating point number to a character string. In case of a character stream (such as the standard output stream), the  `std::scientific` I/O manipulator can be used.

A floating point number itself doesn't contain a textual representation, and it is not possible to return a textual representation from a function that returns a floating point number.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a double that uses scientific notation, rather `print` them as scientific notations. You'll need to use the `std::scientific` manipulator defined in `<iomanip>`.